# Xcode Swift 4, Как программно узнать включен ли Wi-Fi?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, wifi, swift4

Всем привет!
Кто-нибудь знает как программно определить в каком положении находится тумблер Wi-Fi? Даже не важно подключен он к сети или нет, просто включен или выключен. Работаю в Swift 4.

[image]

Comment: Единственное что возможно сделать, это определить если устройство подключено к интернету по Wi-Fi. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39849755/how-to-check-if-wifi-is-on-or-off-in-ios-swift-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В Swift 4 работает вот этот код:

```
func isWifiEnabled() -> Bool {
    var addresses = [String]()

    var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>? = nil
    guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return false }

    var ptr = ifaddr
    while ptr != nil { defer { ptr = ptr?.pointee.ifa_next }
        addresses.append(String(cString: (ptr?.pointee.ifa_name)!))
    }

    var counts:[String:Int] = [:]

    for item in addresses {
        counts[item] = (counts[item] ?? 0) + 1
    }

    freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
    return (counts["awdl0"])! > 1 ? true : false
}
```

Проверил на реальных устройствах iPhone5s(iOS10, iOS11), iPod5(iOS9) - все отлично!

Не работает в симуляторе. Всем спасибо за помощь!!

Answer (score 3):

[вопрос на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12906171/iphone-wifi-on-or-off)

```
func isWifiEnabled() -> Bool {
        var addresses = [String]()
    
        var ifaddr : UnsafeMutablePointer<ifaddrs>?
        guard getifaddrs(&ifaddr) == 0 else { return false }
        guard let firstAddr = ifaddr else { return false }
    
        for ptr in sequence(first: firstAddr, next: { $0.pointee.ifa_next }) {
            addresses.append(String(cString: ptr.pointee.ifa_name))
        }
    
        freeifaddrs(ifaddr)
        return addresses.contains("awdl0")
    }
```

Не работает на Iphone 4
Там приведены и другие варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать хорошую [библиотеку](https://github.com/ashleymills/Reachability.swift).

```
if reachability.isReachable {
   if reachability.isReachableViaWiFi {
     print("Инет через вайфай")
   } else {
     print("Мобильный инет")
   }
} else {
   print("Сеть недоступна")
}
```